# Get to element in multi-dimensional array using an undetermined number of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a bit of weird one, but I can't get my head around it. I have a multidimensional array that has an unknown length and unknown number of dimensions. I also have an array of keys like so:

```
$keys = array(0, 2, 1, 0);
```

Now, if this array of keys had a determined size I would simply access my multidimensional array like so:

```
$multidimensional_array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]];
```

The problem is that it doesn't, the length of the keys array will change a lot. Does anyone know of a loop that could iterate across the keys arrays and then access the multidimensional array accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming such array:

```
$multidimensional_array = array(
   0 => array(
       2 => array(
           1 => array(
               0 => 'value'        
           )
       )
   )
);
```

And these keys:

```
$keys = array(0, 2, 1, 0);
```

You can do:

```
$current = $multidimensional_array; 
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $current = $current[$key];
}

var_dump($current); //'value'
```

Edit:

Here's an example with references.

```
$current = &$multidimensional_array;  // <- $current is reference
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $current = &$current[$key];   // <- $current is reference again
}

var_dump($current); //'value'
$current = 'otherValue'; // $multidimensional_array[0][2][1][0] value changed to 'otherValue'

unset($current); // remove reference to be sure you won't break something later by an accident
```

https://3v4l.org/OuAiQ

Comment: Yep, this is the kind of thing I needed. Didn't think to use a temporary variable that changes each time to the next key.

Comment: Ahhh found the issue with this though. Because this creates a new variable `$current`, it means that I can't change the values of the `$multidimensional_array`, I can only read them from the temporarily created `$current` array. But it's a nice try.

Comment: You can use reference then. But be careful with references as the can be tricky sometimes. In order to be "safe" always `unset` reference variable before reusing it. Other way some confusing stuff may happen.

Comment: By using references? I'm not sure I know what you mean. I don't suppose you could give an example?

Comment: @Pigeon I've added a sample snippet with reference.

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't work. During the foreach loop, when you assign the `$current = $current[$key];` you are actually changing the entire multidimensional array because it is referenced therefore losing all the content. Sorry @dragoste

Comment: It should be `$current = &$current[$key]`. Just a typo.

Comment: You did it! haha wow, that's actually kinda difficult to get my head around but it does work. Nice dragoste. Thanks